# gulp browserify and bromote

Tags: node.js, browserify, google-api-nodejs-client, browserify-shim

My project is using **[gulp-starter](https://github.com/greypants/gulp-starter)** which has quite a bit of wiring already implemented with **[browserify](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify)** and I'm now trying to add **[bromote](https://github.com/thlorenz/bromote)** to this project.

I found this reference to implement **bromote** with **browserify**  [browserify & factor-bundle dependency ids](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24414614/browserify-factor-bundle-dependency-ids) and tried to get it working.

**Here is my resulting gist:**
https://gist.github.com/newtonianb/18f8bcd23ee9762324c6

It compiles fine but I'm not able to access my export. From my understanding, whatever you export in bromote you can then use it like so within your javascript source files

```
var bromote = require('bromote');
bromote.your_export_name(function(x) {});
```

But in my javascript source files when I try require('bromote') I get

```
events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: Cannot find module node_moduleromotelibexport-remote.js' from 'node_modules\bromote\loaders'
  at node_modules\browserify\node_modules\resolve\lib\async.js:50:17
  at process (node_modules\browserify\node_modules\resolve\lib\async.js:119:43)
  at node_modules\browserify\node_modules\resolve\lib\async.js:128:21
  at load (node_modules\browserify\node_modules\resolve\lib\async.js:60:43)
  at node_modules\browserify\node_modules\resolve\lib\async.js:66:22
  at node_modules\browserify\node_modules\resolve\lib\async.js:21:47
  at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you need is google maps, drop bromote and just use browserify with the `google-maps` npm module.  For the most part, your best bet is to see if there's something that will already work with browserify.

Comment: this may not do what you expect. Look at this line of code:
     `GoogleMapsLoader.createLoader = function() {`
      `script = document.createElement('script');`
      `script.type = 'text/javascript';`
      `script.src = GoogleMapsLoader.createUrl();`
      `document.body.appendChild(script);`
     `};`

Thats in the npm module you referenced. That module, all it does is build a script tag in memory and shove it on the page. Any issues related to the dom lifecycle, preloading, all of that, will still be there.